# Redis INCR, SORT and TTL at the same time?

Tags: node.js, sorting, redis, increment, ttl

I plan on using Redis to store some informations for my project :
- page view 
- click on specific button on page

About the page view, I wanted use information to sort it all and get the 10  most seen pages.
But it means I need to use INCR, SORT and TTL as I only want the last day views.
I've been around redis website but It seems that I cant use list, I can use sets or sorted sets.
So I'm a bit lost.
Should I give up some thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track - Sorted Sets will get this done for you.

Use a Sorted Set per day, e.g. for today's date use a key name such as `page-views:20160317`, and use a TTL (the [`EXPIRE`](http://redis.io/commands/expire) command) on that key just so the dataset's size doesn't grow indefinitely.

Each member in the Sorted Set is a unique page - I assume you have an ID property that can be used for that. The score for each page/member is, naturally, the number of views that that page had during the period (day). Increment the score with [`ZINCRBY`](http://redis.io/commands/zincrby) (or if your Redis' version is > 3.0.2, the `INCR` switch of the [`ZADD`](http://redis.io/commands/zadd) command).

The top 10 viewed pages can be begotten with a call to `ZREVRANGE page-views:20160317 0 9`.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. What's great is that your gave me both the same answer so I know it is the right one for me. You guys are great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're kinda awesome yourself too ;)

Comment: :) And what if in all those sorted pages, there are categories and I would like to get the top 10 of a specific category. Should I have a sorted Set for all categories added to the main one? I know I'm getting less awesome!

Comment: A Sorted Set per category is the straightforward and easiest... Awesomeness can only grow, never diminish.

Comment: Alright. And should I keep a main Sorted Set with all page view duplicated in order to get the overall top 10? Or should I use ZUNIONSTORE to  merge all Sorted Sets and get overall top 10 this way ?

Comment: I'd precompute instead of doing real time unions if the all top 10 query, unless it is rarely executed.

Comment: if i did a zadd with a ttl wouldnt all the values expire after the specified interval?

Answer (score 1):

Redis is a swiss army knife so there's always more than one way to do it.  Here's another..

You could use ZADD to increment the view count for a page in a sorted set (one operation per page click) and use ZREVRANGE to list the page counts in order of most seen.

To keep Redis clean you could either call EXPIRE after each ZADD or just DELETE the set (schedule an EXE, or maybe a LUA script?) once a day.  Or alternatively, include the date in the set name and run a job periodically to clean-up old sets.

Comment: Ok I understand. And by calling EXPIRE after each ZADD, will it decreate the same way it increased ? If it's the case, this is amazing! Thanks a lot !